# edmx computed column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity, edmx

I have created an EDMX in visual studio 2010 SP1. It has been built from an existing database.

There are a number of database generated columns (ie, non nullable with GETDATE() as the default value).

The EDMX though does not seem to detect these columns and isn't setting "StoreGeneratedPattern" to "Computed". I am going to have to set these manually for the thing to work!

The database is very large so this is not ideal.

Is this a bug with the EDMX generation or am I likely to be doing something wrong?

Many thanks
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bug. It simply works this way because default constraint setting column to current date is not computed column. Computed column change its value every time you save a record - example is timestamp. Moreover properties using `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity` or `Computed` cannot be set from your application. Your column accepts other value so EF cannot make it store generated by default - it is up to you to make the decision.

If you want to use default value from database for all records set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`. It will ensure that the value is set and queried during insert. Setting the pattern to `Computed` will create unnecessary query after each update.